# LUA windows: How do I launch windows metro app with Unified Remote script

Tags: scripting, lua, windows-8.1, execute, launch

I'm trying to make a custom remote for unified remote server in windows 8.1

The sample scripts have os.start(command). It works for something like calc, but I'm trying to launch a metro app 'netflix://' and Lua doesn't seem to want to accept it - I think it's not taking the front slashes.

Is there a way to get Lua to launch a metro app in windows? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `os.execute()` command, to run commands that open files and run based on protocol association, you need to use `start` command:

```
os.execute("start http://google.com")
```

If you need to put the parameter in quotes, then make sure to include a pair of empty quotes as the first parameter:

```
os.execute([[start "" "netflix://..."]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For `os.start()`, it seems that you have to pass the whole path to a command. The [Unified Remote API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336114/lua-windows-how-do-i-launch-windows-metro-app-with-unified-remote-script) states that it should match installed applications, but I believe it might only be applicable to applications with binaries in the PATH, which is why their example of `calc` works.

With this in mind, and knowing that `start` works well directly from PoweShell, this command does what we need:

```
os.start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "netflix:");
```

Answering this old question since it's the top google hit when looking for launching windows10 apps with Lua for Unified Remote

As a side note, due to limitations on the Netflix Win10 app, I ended up simply opening Firefox and giving it the Netflix URL. Assuming default installation:

```
os.start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "https://www.netflix.com");
```